# Serialize/Reg ex

Tags: javascript, regex, serialization

I use serialize function to get all the values of my form. 
My problem is how can i extract only the value in the generated **url** string of the serialize function and split it into an array.

```
var input = $('#addForm').serialize();

deviceBrand=itemBrand&deviceModel=itemModel&deviceSerial=itemSerial&deviceType=Desktop&deviceStatus=Available&deviceDesc=item+description //generated url string
```

i need string function to extract each `string between "=" and "&"` and put each String into an array.

Comment: `serialize` is for sending in an AJAX request. Don't use it for communicating internally within Javascript, create an object.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I posted an answer, isn't that good enough?

Comment: late read, i will try

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `serialize`, use [`serializeArray`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). It creates an array of objects of the form `{name: "xxx", value: "yyy" }` that you can process more easily.

```
var input = $("#addForm").serializeArray();
var values = input.map(x => x.value);
```

You can also make an object with all the `name: value` properties:

```
var object = {};
input.map(x => object[x.name] = x.value);
```

Comment: is it possible to turn this in a json?

Comment: `values_json = JSON.stringify(values)`

Comment: do it output like this:, Brand: brandVal, Model: modelVal, ...etc.

Comment: The question says you just want an array of the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to unserialize the string,

```
(function($){
$.unserialize = function(serializedString){
    var str = decodeURI(serializedString);
    var pairs = str.split('&');
    var obj = {}, p, idx, val;
    for (var i=0, n=pairs.length; i < n; i++) {
        p = pairs[i].split('=');
        idx = p[0];

        if (idx.indexOf("[]") == (idx.length - 2)) {
            // Eh um vetor
            var ind = idx.substring(0, idx.length-2)
            if (obj[ind] === undefined) {
                obj[ind] = [];
            }
            obj[ind].push(p[1]);
        }
        else {
            obj[idx] = p[1];
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
})(jQuery);
```